# creating phrases with multi-token terms for sphinx queries

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx, subquery

I am following on a request to search for a list of queries and was told the best approach would be to use phrases with multi-token terms. I am a little confused on what this means exactly and rather than responding wanted to verify my interpretation.

I understood that to mean creating phrases with each possible combination using all the queries. We are talking about 500+ queries so just want to make sure I am doing this correctly. For example:

```
apple, banana, orange, grapes, blueberries, litchi, watermelon, peach, tomato

query=("apple banana") | ("apple orange") | ("apple grapes")
```

Now to manually do this for so many queries would be a pain. I thought something like this:

```
query="apple (banana | orange | grapes | blueberries ...)"
```

If I did this for each term, then would this reflect phrases with multi-token terms? If not then please could someone clarify what it means and what an example query would look like?

Comment: I think the only way of clarifing the request, is to ask who made the request for more details. If you dont understand the request, not sure how you expect us to. (difficult for you to explain, what you acknowledge you dont understand!)

Comment: The "open sesame" to the door of learning is "I don't understand".